# Get count of particular values and the total based on another column value in dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe `df`:

| names | status |
| --- | --- |
| John | Completed |
| James | To Do |
| Jill | To Do |
| Robert | In Progress |
| Jill | To Do |
| Jill | To Do |
| Marina | Completed |
| Evy | Completed |
| Evy | Completed |

Now I want the count of each type of status for each user. I can get it like this for all types of statuses.

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.names,df.status).reset_index("names")
```

So now the resulting `df` is

| status | names | Completed | In Progress | To Do |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | James | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | Robert | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | John | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | Marina | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | Jill | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 5 | Evy | 2 | 0 | 0 |

So my problem is how can I specify only a particular type of status value to be counted? For eg: I want only the values of `In Progress` and `Completed` and not `To Do`. And how can I add a extra column to the above called as `Total Statuses`, that will actually be the total number of rows for each name in the original dataframe?

Desired Dataframe:

| status | names | Completed | In Progress | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | James | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | Robert | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | John | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | Marina | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | Jill | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 5 | Evy | 2 | 0 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

pass `margins` and `margins_name` parameters in `pd.crosstab()`:

```
df=(pd.crosstab(df.names,df.status,margins=True,margins_name='Total').iloc[:-1]
      .reset_index().drop('To Do',1))
```

OR

via `crosstab()`+`assign()`

```
df=(pd.crosstab(df.names,df.status).assign(Total=lambda x:x.sum(1))
      .reset_index().drop('To Do',1))
```

OR

In 2 steps:

```
df=pd.crosstab(df.names,df.status)
df=df.assign(Total=df.sum(1)).drop('To Do',1).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the total from the addition of the three previous columns:

```
df['Total'] = (df['Completed'] + df['In Progress'] + df['To Do'])
```

Then you can drop the 'to-do' from your new data frame as follows :

```
df = df.drop(columns=['To Do'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['John', 'James', 'Jill', 'Robert', 'Jill', 'Jill', 'Marina', 'Evy', 'Evy'],
                   'status':['Completed', 'To Do', 'To Do', 'In Progress', 'To Do', 'To Do', 'Completed', 'Completed', 'Completed']})
df = pd.crosstab(df.names,df.status).reset_index("names")
df['Total'] = df['Completed'] + df['In Progress'] + df['To Do']
df = df.drop(columns=['To Do'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
status   names  Completed  In Progress  Total
0          Evy          2            0      2
1        James          0            0      1
2         Jill          0            0      3
3         John          1            0      1
4       Marina          1            0      1
5       Robert          0            1      1
```

I can't comprehend what kind of sorting system you are using. But I think you will manage to do that yourself.